# what's the use of "call name" in Objective-C params?

Tags: ios, objective-c

an Objective-C method has params, and each param except the first one has two names:call name and var name, for example:

```
-SomeMessage:(type)varName callName2:(type)varName2
```

so, what's the use of callName ? why we need two names for an param?

Comment: emmm... those are not _two_ names, that is a method's interface, in your exmaple the method's header is `–SomeMessage:callName2:` and the `varName` and `varName2` are the local variables' names in the method's scope. please see more here about the language's basics: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a better method example:

```
- dataForKey:(NSString *)key withEncoding:(NSString *)encoding;
```

The first name, how you call it, is actually part of the method name, the whole method name is:

```
- dataForKey:withEncoding:
```

(including the colons).

Obj-C prefers method names that can be read like sentences. This is useful in context of the caller. In languages like Java or C++ the method would be called like this

```
data = object.getData("key", "ASCII")
```

which is difficult to understand for the readers because they doesn't know what the parameters stand for. In Obj-C

```
data = [object dataForKey:@"key" withEncoding:@"ASCII"];
```

is easy to understand without looking at the method declaration.

Comment: actually, IDE will help us, just move the mouse to the function, a prompt will shows.

Comment: @lovespring That is still slowing you down when you are trying to understand the code.

Comment: Can we use named param in a radom order? in c++/java we have to follow the order that the function declared.

Comment: @lovespring Again, they are not named parameters, they are a part of method name. Changing the order means changing the method name - calling a whole different method. BTW Java has no named parameters. C++ doesn't have named parameters either although you can mock them using setter calls ("named parameters idiom").

Comment: Ha ha. That was quite funny - that objective C is easier to understand & other languages syntax is more difficult to understand

Comment: Obj-C syntax is very easy to understand. It's not complicated, you are probably just unfamiliar with it because it differs from other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Its to make your code more readable, each "call name" is a description of a parameter

so instead of C style having `myMethod(5, 4, 9, 2)`

you would have `[self myMethodWithParam:5 andACoolNumber:4 thisShouldBeNine:9 divisor:2];`

which just helps you understand what the functions parameters need to be, its optional, but you should always do it to help with code maintainability

Answer (score -1):

This is how it works what you wrote is correct "Somemessage" and "callName2" are part of the method name while varName and varName2 are variables .

callname2 is optional , generally it is used if we want to give any definition for the variable we writes after that

Hope this helped you.

Comment: I said the same right that it is description of the parameter